# How to retrieve the most recent confirmed Covid data for a set of countries

Tags: import, code-review, code-request, resourceobject

This `code` works as expected for 30 countries:

```
DateListLogPlot[Callout[Tooltip[10^5 #2/#1["Population"], CommonName[#1]], #1] & @@@ 
 Normal@ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", "WorldCountries"][
 TakeLargestBy[#ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &, 30]][All, {#Country, #ConfirmedCases} &], 
 Sequence[PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1.5, ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotLabel -> "estimated confirmed cases per 100K people (log \scale)"]]
```

I wish to construct the plot for a set of selected countries:

```
cList={"Japan","France","Brazil","UnitedKingdom"};
```

**EDIT**

Using the following `Manipulate`, I can get COVID-19 confirmed cases across countries and plot the moving average time series of daily confirmed cases across countries:

```
(*Single country analysis: most recent observation and plot of time series Confirmed Cases*)

ResourceRemove[ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]];
covid = ResourceData[ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]];
cList={"Japan","France","Brazil","UnitedKingdom"};

Manipulate[
 Row[{
   ListLinePlot[
    covid[
      SelectFirst[#Country == 
         Entity["Country", cList[[country]]] &], {"ConfirmedCases"}][
     All, MovingAverage[Differences[#], Quantity[1, "Weeks"]] &], 
    Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400
    ],
   Last[N[
     Normal[covid[
          SelectFirst[#Country == 
             Entity["Country", 
              cList[[country]]] &], {"ConfirmedCases"}][All, 
         MovingAverage[Differences[#], 
           Quantity[1, "Weeks"]] &][[1]]][[All, 2]]]]
   }],
 {{country, 1, "country : "}, Thread[Range[Length[cList]] -> cList], 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 TrackedSymbols :> {country},
 FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", 
    Style["Time series of confirmed cases and the most recent 
    observation", Larger, Bold, Black]}}
 ]
```

In my actual list of countries, there are four countries with state-level data. I developed (Thanks to @LouisB) the following `Manipulate` that extracts the total state-level data:

```
 cListext={"Unitedstates", "Australia", "Canada", "China"};
 Manipulate[
 case = Entity["Country", cListext[[country]]];
 data = covid[
     Select[(#Country == case && 
         Not[Head[#AdministrativeDivision] === Missing]) &]][[All, 
     4]] // Total;
 Row[{
   DateListPlot[
      MovingAverage[Differences[data], Quantity[1, "Weeks"]], 
      ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
      PlotLabel -> case["Name"], 
      GridLines -> True] & /@ {"ConfirmedCases"},
   Last[N[
     Normal@MovingAverage[Differences[data], 
          Quantity[1, "Weeks"]] &[[1]][[All, 2]]]]
   }],
 {{country, 1, "country : "}, 
  Thread[Range[Length[cListext]] -> cListext], 
  ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 TrackedSymbols :> {country},
 FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", Style["Aggregating cumulative state data into country-level data", Larger, Bold, Black]}}
 ]
```

Both of these `Manipulate` codes work as expected. My goal is to combine the two `Manipulate` codes in a single `Manipulate` and be able to get times series country-level daily confirmed cases, and construct a table with two columns: `{cListCombined, "very last observation of confirmed cases"}`

```
cListCombined={cList, cListext}//Flatten
```

**EDIT 2**

Instead of:

```
covid = ResourceData[ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]];
```

if I use `WorldCountries` in extracting the data:

```
covid = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
   "WorldCountries"];
```

the first `Manipulate` operation performs what I aim to, and no need for the second `Manipulate` (pointed out by @LouisB).

Comment: Instead of `TakeLargestBy[#ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &, 30]`  try  `Select[MemberQ[Entity["Country", #] & /@ cList, #Country] &]`

Comment: @LouisB: Thanks for your help. It works. I like to accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @LouisB: I wonder if you can show me how to get the "Country" level data only. I face a problem with countries having various states like the USA, China, etc. I do not want to get state-level data. I just need country-level total numbers of COVID.

Comment: Yes, I will look at the country-level problem.

Comment: @LouisB: Thanks very much.

Comment: @LouisB: I found one of your earlier posts about the COVID data extraction. With minor changes, your code works for individual country: `usa = Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"];
With[{data = 
   res[Select[(#Country == usa && 
        Not[Head[#AdministrativeDivision] === Missing]) &]]}, 
 GraphicsColumn[
  DateListPlot[data[All, #] // Total, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
     GridLines -> True] & /@ {"ConfirmedCases"}]]`. Please consider my case with a list of countries having various states and I like to have total confirmed cases for the list concerned.

Comment: To my knowledge, the best way to get country-level data is to use "WorldCountries", as you have done in your question.  I don't understand how you are getting state-level data, if you are using "WorldCountries".  Please consider adding a brief example of the state-level versus country-level problem to your question.  Also, my previous answer was rather uninformed, since I did not know about "WorldCountries" at that time.

Comment: @LouiseB: I will edit my question. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @LouisB: You are absolutely right in pointing out the use of "WorldCountries`. In my actual `codes` that was mixed up but now all is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer to my own question above.

```
ResourceRemove[ResourceObject["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]];
covid = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", "WorldCountries"];

allcountries = {"Afghanistan", "AlandIslands", "Albania", "Algeria", 
   "AmericanSamoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", 
   "AntiguaBarbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", 
   "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", 
   "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", 
   "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "BonaireSintEustatiusAndSaba", 
   "BosniaHerzegovina", "Botswana", "BouvetIsland", "Brazil", 
   "BritishIndianOceanTerritory", "BritishVirginIslands", "Brunei", 
   "Bulgaria", "BurkinaFaso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", 
   "Canada", "CapeVerde", "CaymanIslands", "CentralAfricanRepublic", 
   "Chad", "Chile", "China", "ChristmasIsland", "CocosKeelingIslands",
    "Colombia", "Comoros", "CookIslands", "CostaRica", "Croatia", 
   "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "CzechRepublic", 
   "DemocraticRepublicCongo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", 
   "DominicanRepublic", "EastTimor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "ElSalvador",
    "EquatorialGuinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", 
   "FalklandIslands", "FaroeIslands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", 
   "FrenchGuiana", "FrenchPolynesia", 
   "FrenchSouthernAndAntarcticLands", "Gabon", "Gambia", "GazaStrip", 
   "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", 
   "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea",
    "GuineaBissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "HongKong", 
   "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", 
   "Ireland", "IsleOfMan", "Israel", "Italy", "IvoryCoast", "Jamaica",
    "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", 
   "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", 
   "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", 
   "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
   "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "MarshallIslands", 
   "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", 
   "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", 
   "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", 
   "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "NewCaledonia", "NewZealand", 
   "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "NorfolkIsland", 
   "NorthKorea", "NorthernMarianaIslands", "Norway", "Oman", 
   "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "PapuaNewGuinea", "Paraguay", 
   "Peru", "Philippines", "PitcairnIslands", "Poland", "Portugal", 
   "PuertoRico", "Qatar", "RepublicCongo", "Reunion", "Romania", 
   "Russia", "Rwanda", "SaintBarthelemy", "SaintHelena", 
   "SaintKittsNevis", "SaintLucia", "SaintMartin", 
   "SaintPierreMiquelon", "SaintVincentGrenadines", "Samoa", 
   "SanMarino", "SaoTomePrincipe", "SaudiArabia", "Senegal", "Serbia",
    "Seychelles", "SierraLeone", "Singapore", "SintMaarten", 
   "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "SolomonIslands", "Somalia", "SouthAfrica",
    "SouthGeorgiaAndTheSouthSandwichIslands", "SouthKorea", 
   "SouthSudan", "Spain", "SriLanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard",
    "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", 
   "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", 
   "TrinidadTobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", 
   "TurksCaicosIslands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", 
   "UnitedArabEmirates", "UnitedKingdom", "UnitedStates", 
   "UnitedStatesMinorOutlyingIslands", "UnitedStatesVirginIslands", 
   "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "VaticanCity", "Venezuela", 
   "Vietnam", "WallisFutuna", "WestBank", "WesternSahara", "Yemen", 
   "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"};

cList = {"Australia", "Austria", "Belgium", "Canada", "Chile", 
   "CzechRepublic", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", 
   "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Israel", 
   "Italy", "Japan", "SouthKorea", "Latvia", "Lithuania", 
   "Luxembourg", "Netherlands", "NewZealand", "Norway", "Poland", 
   "Portugal", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", 
   "Switzerland", "Turkey", "UnitedKingdom", "UnitedStates", 
   "Argentina", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Cambodia", 
   "Colombia", "CostaRica", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "India", "Indonesia",
    "HongKong", "Kazakhstan", "Malaysia", "Malta", "Morocco", "Peru", 
   "Philippines", "Romania", "Russia", "SaudiArabia", "Singapore", 
   "SouthAfrica", "Taiwan", "Thailand", "Tunisia", "Vietnam", 
   "Mexico", "China"};

RoW = {"Afghanistan", "AlandIslands", "Albania", "Algeria", 
   "AmericanSamoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", 
   "AntiguaBarbuda", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", 
   "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belize", "Benin", 
   "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "BonaireSintEustatiusAndSaba", 
   "BosniaHerzegovina", "Botswana", "BouvetIsland", 
   "BritishIndianOceanTerritory", "BritishVirginIslands", 
   "BurkinaFaso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "CapeVerde", "CaymanIslands",
    "CentralAfricanRepublic", "Chad", "ChristmasIsland", 
   "CocosKeelingIslands", "Comoros", "CookIslands", "Cuba", "Curacao",
    "DemocraticRepublicCongo", "Djibouti", "Dominica", 
   "DominicanRepublic", "EastTimor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "ElSalvador",
    "EquatorialGuinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "FalklandIslands", 
   "FaroeIslands", "Fiji", "FrenchGuiana", "FrenchPolynesia", 
   "FrenchSouthernAndAntarcticLands", "Gabon", "Gambia", "GazaStrip", 
   "Georgia", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greenland", "Grenada", 
   "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", 
   "GuineaBissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Iran", "Iraq", 
   "IsleOfMan", "IvoryCoast", "Jamaica", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kenya", 
   "Kiribati", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Lebanon", 
   "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Macau", 
   "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Maldives", "Mali", 
   "MarshallIslands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
   "Mayotte", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", 
   "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", 
   "Nauru", "Nepal", "NewCaledonia", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", 
   "Niue", "NorfolkIsland", "NorthernMarianaIslands", "NorthKorea", 
   "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "PapuaNewGuinea", 
   "Paraguay", "PitcairnIslands", "PuertoRico", "Qatar", 
   "RepublicCongo", "Reunion", "Rwanda", "SaintBarthelemy", 
   "SaintHelena", "SaintKittsNevis", "SaintLucia", "SaintMartin", 
   "SaintPierreMiquelon", "SaintVincentGrenadines", "Samoa", 
   "SanMarino", "SaoTomePrincipe", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", 
   "SierraLeone", "SintMaarten", "SolomonIslands", "Somalia", 
   "SouthGeorgiaAndTheSouthSandwichIslands", "SouthSudan", "SriLanka",
    "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard", "Swaziland", "Syria", 
   "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", 
   "TrinidadTobago", "Turkmenistan", "TurksCaicosIslands", "Tuvalu", 
   "Uganda", "Ukraine", "UnitedArabEmirates", 
   "UnitedStatesMinorOutlyingIslands", "UnitedStatesVirginIslands", 
   "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "VaticanCity", "Venezuela", 
   "WallisFutuna", "WestBank", "WesternSahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", 
   "Zimbabwe"};

(*final demand adjustment function*)
delta[infBar_, delBar_, infObs_] := Piecewise[{{1, infObs <= 0.1*infBar},
    {delBar*(1 + (infObs/infBar - 0.1))/(delBar + (infObs/infBar - 0.1)), 
    infObs > 0.1*infBar} }];

(*Rest of the World COVID-19 Confirmed Cases*)
bir = Manipulate[
   Module[
    {tsRoW, aggRoW, maRoW},
    tsRoW = 
     Normal@covid[
         Select[MemberQ[Entity["Country", #] & /@ RoW, #Country] &]][
        All, {#Country, #ConfirmedCases} &][[All, 2]];
    aggRoW = Normal[TimeSeriesThread[Total, tsRoW]][[All, 2]];
    maRoW = 
     Select[MovingAverage[Differences[aggRoW], 7] // N, 
      FreeQ[#, _Missing] &];
    {
     ListLinePlot[maRoW, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
      PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic],
     delta[infBar, delBar, #] & /@ maRoW // 
      Mean     (*annual FD adjustment factor*)
     }
    ],
   Spacer[40],
   Delimiter,
   {{infBar, 20000, "infection threshold : "}, 5000, 100000, 5000},
   {{delBar, .65, "max rate of reduction in demand : "}, 0, 1, .05},
   TrackedSymbols :> {infBar, delBar},
   FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", 
      Style["Time series of confirmed cases in the RoW and demand \
adjustment factor", Larger, Bold, Black]}}
   ];

(*Single country most recent data on confirmed cases*)
iki = Manipulate[
   Module[
    {veri, maveri, infObs},
    veri = 
     covid[SelectFirst[#Country == 
         Entity["Country", cList[[country]]] &], {"ConfirmedCases"}];
    maveri = 
     veri[All, MovingAverage[Differences[#], Quantity[1, "Weeks"]] &];
    Row[{
      DateListPlot[maveri, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
       ImageSize -> 400, Filling -> Axis, GridLines -> Automatic],
      {
       infObs = 
        Select[N[Normal[maveri[[1]]][[All, 2]]], FreeQ[#, _Missing] &];
       delta[infBar, delBar, #] & /@ infObs // 
        Mean     (*annual FD adjustment factor*)
       }
      }]
    ],
   Spacer[40],
   Delimiter,
   {{country, 1, "country : "}, Thread[Range[Length[cList]] -> cList],
     ControlType -> PopupMenu},
   {{infBar, 20000, "infection threshold : "}, 5000, 100000, 5000},
   {{delBar, .65, "max rate of reduction in demand : "}, 0, 1, .05},
   TrackedSymbols :> {country, infBar, delBar},
   FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", 
      Style["Time series of confirmed cases across countries and \
demand adjustment factor", Larger, Bold, Black]}}
   ];

(*Final demand adjustment parameters across countries*)
Manipulate[
 Do[
  veri = covid[
    SelectFirst[#Country == 
       Entity["Country", cList[[i]]] &], {"ConfirmedCases"}];
  maveri = 
   veri[All, MovingAverage[Differences[#], Quantity[1, "Weeks"]] &];
  out = Select[N@Flatten@Normal[maveri][[All, 2]][[1, 1]], 
    FreeQ[#, _Missing] &];
  del[i] = delta[infBar, delBar, #] & /@ out // Mean, {i, 
   Length[cList]}
  ];
 adjFact = Table[{cList[[i]], del[i]}, {i, Length[cList]}];
 TableForm[adjFact, TableHeadings -> {None, {"", "Adj-Factor"}}],
 Spacer[40],
 Delimiter,
 {{infBar, 20000, "infection threshold : "}, 5000, 100000, 5000},
 {{delBar, .65, "max rate of reduction in demand : "}, 0, 1, .05},
 TrackedSymbols :> {infBar, delBar},
 FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", 
    Style["Final demand adjustment parameters across countries", 
     Larger, Bold, Black]}}
 ];
```

With the above `code` one can do the following 3 tasks:

1. Time series of the daily 7-day moving average of confirmed infections across 64 countries (rest of the world is calculated as a separate country);
2. The country-level final demand adjustment parameter is calculated for each country; and
3. Every time this code is run, the most recent time series and final demand adjustment parameters are automatically calculated.